# Unsatisfied dependencies for injecting EJB service into web (war)

Tags: ejb, cdi

My beans.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

My service (backend - type EJB) looks like this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Default
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Inject
private UserDao userDao;

@Inject
private UserMapper mapper;
```

and `@Named` annotated bean uses this (web):

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@Named("indexMBean")
public class IndexMBean extends AbstractViewBean {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;
```

Build was success, but deploy gives me this exception:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserService with qualifiers @Default
>     at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private hu.food.bean.IndexMBean.userService

how can I set the Default injection for UserService?

the log says:

> 2018-11-12 11:28:25,706 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."kaJava-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kaJava-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1728)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
>       at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserService with qualifiers @Default
>     at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private hu.food.bean.IndexMBean.userService
>     at hu.food.bean.IndexMBean.userService(IndexMBean.java:0)

Comment: It shows your code is missing dependency injection, show all logs or attache file that we can easily track it

Comment: @DeedarAliBrohi attached a log

Comment: Have you tried with totally empty beans.xml so not even elements `<?xml ...` or`<beans/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `annotated` discovery mode in your `beans.xml` this means that only beans with so called **Bean defining annotations** are discovered and registered as beans. Consult [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations) for all the annotations that belong there; for your use case, you are missing **bean scope**.

If you remove `@Default` qualifier from `UserServiceImpl` (it is useless, it is added there anyway; [spec link](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#builtin_qualifiers)) and add a scope to the bean, it should work.
Based on how your bean should behave (from the lifecycle point of view), you can make it `@ApplicationScoped`, `@SessionScoped`, `@RequestScoped`, `@ConversationScoped`, `@Dependent` (, `@Singleton`).

Comment: How is this answer fundamentally different than the already existing answer?

Comment: I don't know, refers to actual CDI spec which should be the source (Weld docs rely on users knowing CDI and build on that) and explains default qualifier because that could bring some seemingly weird behaviour if OP starts adding other qualifiers on that bean. Otherwise yea, not as different.

Answer (score 4):

You set bean-discovery mode to annotated. so only beans annotated with a scope type will be detected

```
bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
```

please add a scope type annotation like @dependent to your bean

```
@Default
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
@Dependent
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
```

http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations says:

> The set of bean defining annotations contains:
>
> - @ApplicationScoped, @SessionScoped, @ConversationScoped and
> - @RequestScoped annotations,
> - all other normal scope types,
> - @Interceptor and @Decorator annotations,
> - all stereotype annotations (i.e. annotations annotated with
>     @Stereotype),
> - and the @Dependent scope annotation.